# Install Sametime connect on Fedora 11 Leonidas machine

Tags: fedora11

I have installed IBM Lotus sametime client on my fedora 11 Leonidas box.
I have the following rpms installed,
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.i386.rpm
sametime-connect-lin-7.5.1-1.i386.rpm
xterm-237-1.fc10.i386.rpm

While opening the sametime client, it tries to open the EClipse IDE and after that both the same time cliet window and Eclipse IDE window are getting closed abruptly.

COuld you please let me know if there is any way to resolve this error.

Thanks,
Ricks.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the sametime 8.5.1 in Fedora 14 and ubuntu 11.10 without any issue.

Follow below url for install and download the sametime 8.5.1 version.

http://ubuntulinux.co.in/blog/ubuntu/ibm-sametime-installation-in-linux/

Video tutorial for installing sametime

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vd9ReHWawM0